# How to get multi-dimensional cookie as variable?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to get the cookie that has been set before into json, I get the cookie with this:

```
$cookie = stripslashes($_COOKIE['cookieBook']);
$cookie_decoded = json_decode($cookie);
```

and the result:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Book A
            [url] => https:// Book A URL /
        )
    )
```

I wanted to get the id as variable and insert it to an array that display first post of a category.

```
$catid = 'id value from the cookie'; 
$newest = array('posts_per_page' => 1, 
'cat' => $catid
); 
$books = new WP_Query($newest)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: as I said before, I wanted to get the id as a variable (like I write $catid in the example).

Comment: try this. $catid = $cookie_decoded[0]['id'];

Comment: or if you have multiple stdClass then you must be use foreach.

Comment: I got error, Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: ohh, i forgot to add 'true' after json_decode. Thanks, you can create the answer, i wili accept it.